# Regarding Raspberry Pi and water flow sensor integration

Tags: pi-2, sensor

I want to use water flow sensor using Raspberry Pi 2 but the water flow sensor accepts only 5v as a input and gives the pulses of 5v as a output but my Raspberry Pi can take only 3.3v.

Is this possible to implement?

And if possible code please.

Comment: Could you post a link to the sensor you are using so we can check the details?

Answer (score 1):

This is no software issue.

Look at the sensor's datasheet, it might be able to operate at 3.3V just fine.
If it **doesn't**, you have to build a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) between the sensor's output and your Pi's input.

> This question decides whether to connect the sensor's voltage in to 5V or 3V!
>   In turn, it determines the maximum voltage applied to Pi' GPIOs.
>   So never connect it to 5V **without** the voltage divider!

Assuming your sensor requires almost no power, this can be achieved easily with for example 3x [10K Ohm resistors](https://www.amazon.de/Widerstand-St%C3%BCck-Kohleschicht-Widerst%C3%A4nde-Resistor/dp/B00IYUWT2A).

```
R2 = 10K
R1 = 5K (2x 10K in parallel)
Hence, 10K/15K =~ 0.66
0.66 * 5V = 3.3V
```